# Copy file sheets from an excel file to another file

Tags: java

this java code makes it possible to copy the sheets of an excel file and to paste them in another one, but I have an exception on this line:

**CellStyle style = c.getCellStyle();**

I can not paste styles
Thank you in advance for your help !

````
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(inputFile);
XSSFWorkbook inputWorkbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
int inputSheetCount=inputWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();
System.out.println("Input sheetCount: "+inputSheetCount);

File outputFile=new File("/var/opt/data/flat/sidre/talend/projects/GRDF/Reporting/tmp/WindowsPatchs/fileb.xlsx");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
XSSFWorkbook outputWorkbook=new XSSFWorkbook();

for(int i=0;i<inputSheetCount;i++)
{
    XSSFSheet inputSheet=inputWorkbook.getSheetAt(i); 
    String inputSheetName=inputWorkbook.getSheetName(i); 
    XSSFSheet outputSheet=outputWorkbook.createSheet(inputSheetName); 


    int rowCount=inputSheet.getLastRowNum(); 
    System.out.println(rowCount+" rows in inputsheet "+inputSheet.getSheetName());

    int currentRowIndex=0;
    if(rowCount>0)
    {
        Iterator rowIterator=inputSheet.iterator();
        XSSFRow row;
        while(rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            int currentCellIndex=0;
            row = (XSSFRow)rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();

            while(cellIterator.hasNext())
            {
                String cellData=cellIterator.next().toString();
                Cell c = cellIterator.next();
                CellStyle style = c.getCellStyle();

                if(currentCellIndex==0)
                {
                    outputSheet.createRow(currentRowIndex).createCell(currentCellIndex).setCellValue(cellData);
                }
                else
                {
                    outputSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).createCell(currentCellIndex).setCellValue(cellData);
                    //outputSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).createCell(currentCellIndex).setCellStyle(style);

                    //outputSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).createCell(currentCellIndex).setCellValue(cellData);
                    //outputSheet.getRow(currentRowIdex).createCell(currentCellIndex).setCellValue(cellData);
                }

                currentCellIndex++;

            }

            currentRowIndex++;

        }
        System.out.println((currentRowIndex-1)+" rows added to outputsheet "+outputSheet.getSheetName());
            System.out.println();

    }
}

outputWorkbook.write(fos); 
              // Step #10 : At the end of the Program close the FileOutputStream object. 
               fos.close(); 
```
````

Comment: Is there an Office programming stackexchange site where this should go? Or StackOverflow? I don't see any data science here.

Comment: Can you please paste your exception stacktrace?